# 3D obj file has a geometric hole

Tags: printer, 3d, shapes, blender

**The purpose of this post**: I'm making some 3D art with an online sculpting tool called "SculptGL". In this program you are given a pink sphere of vertices and faces, with tools to sculpt the geometry.

**The Problem**: After a bit of stretching and high detail, a hole had developed in the geometry. The hole is a bunch of missing faces that allow you to see the inside of the sculpture.

**What I've tried**: I tried to add some extra material to the area and re-meshed the whole thing. this didn't just fix it, but it also made a hole somewhere else the same size. ive tried covering it all up again and again, trying different tools. by the time i tried it all the shape eventually collapsed and became unsavable. luckily i have a recent save file and can retry as many times as i would like. one other option that should work, would be to manually edit the txt object file and find the issue, but that proved to be way to difficult. especially when you dont even know what your looking for.

if anyone could help that would be great, thanks!